# Vuejs with Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I`m try open a simple bootstrap modal using vuejs, but nothing happens. I want create a modal like a vue component and trigger than with a button on the index.html

This is the vuejs component

```
Vue.component("modal", {

template: `
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>This is a small modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
`
});
```

And this is the HTML

```
<div id="root">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" @click="openModal">
    Launch modal
</button>
</div>

<script>
vue = new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    data: {
        showModal: false
    },
    methods: {
        openModal: function () {
            this.showModal = true
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your setup is generally correct, but you're not using `showModal` in your template, and you're not including your template (`modal` component) in your HTML.

Do those two things and it will work.

Comment: Thanks Tyler, i`m not pay much attention when i'm writed the code and forgot call `showModal`